# Communication between two process using signals in C

Tags: c, process, signals

I must create a program in C who will be communicate between two process by SIGUSR1. This program must will reply back when send and receive signal. I have the code below, but he just sends a signal, why does the receiving function not work?

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkE3z.jpg)

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void send_SIGUSR1();

void main()
{
int pid;

if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    perror("Fork");
    exit(1);
}

if (pid == 0) {
    signal(SIGUSR1, send_SIGUSR1());
}

else
{
    printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGUSR1\n\n");
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
}
}

void send_SIGUSR1()

{
signal(SIGUSR1, send_SIGUSR1);
printf("CHILD: I have received a SIGUSR1\n");
}
```

Comment: Has your child set up its signal handler by the time it receives the signal?  Also, why does your signal handling function call the function that sets a signal handler?

Comment: Can you show me this problems in code?

Comment: Race condition. You send a signal before the other program has a chance to set up a handler.

Comment: So, I must will add sleep() or something?

Comment: Sorry, no, you've got a whole bunch of different errors and I have no idea how it ever compiles. 1. `signal.h` not included. 2 `void main` 3. `send_SIGUSR1()` is a wrong argument to `signal`, you want `send_SIGUSR1`. 4. A signal handler needs to have an `int` parameter. `I recommend `clang -Weverything -Werror`. After you're done with this, add some `sleep`, and/or call `signal` before `fork`. Oh and indent your code.